# how to sum valeus in array when the other values is the same in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i have this object

```
const MyArray = [{name:"vehicle",data:[{y: 500, x: '2022-12-12'},{y: 700, x: '2022-12-12'}]},
{name:"medical",data:[{y: 500, x: '2030-10-12'},{y: 700, x: '2040-12-12'}]}]
```

and i want this output :

bcs its the same date in the same name

```
const MyArray = [{name:"vehicle",data:[{y: 1200, x: '2022-10-12'}]},
{name:"medical",data:[{y: 500, x: '2030-10-12'},{y: 700, x: '2040-12-12'}]}]
```

Comment: What attempts have you made to try and solve this? You should add that code to your question as a [mcve].

Comment: i try this 

```
const newdata = statt.map(item=>
    
    item.map(item2=>
        {

            const a=item2.data.reduce((prev, { x, y }) => {
                prev[x] = prev[x] ? prev[x] + y : y;
                return prev;
              }, {});
            
            return a

        }
        
        
        
        
        )
    
    
    )

```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function addDuplicates(array) {
    const newarr = []
    array.forEach(elem => {
        if (!newarr.some(val => val.x === elem.x)) {
            newarr.push(
                {
                    y: array.filter(value => value.x === elem.x).map(y=>y.y).reduce((p,n)=>p+n,0),
                    x: elem.x
                }
            )
        }
    })
    return newarr
}
const output = MyArray.map(elem=>({...elem,data:addDuplicates(elem.data)}))

console.log(output)
```

---

> i would recommend you if you are using react js then pass the data value in other component and then use the add duplicate function there. It will be simple keeping your components simple and fast processing will be done.